# Why does my function only return the last parmeter

Tags: javascript

Function is only returning 'read' in node. Why not all?

```
function book(title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title
    this.author = author
    this.pages = pages
    this.read = read
    this.info = function() {
        return(title, author, pages, read)
    }
}
const theHobbit = new book('TheHobbit', 'J.R.R. Tolkien', '295 pages', 'read')
console.log(theHobbit.info());
```

Comment: There are no tuples in JavaScript like in Python. The expression `(title, author, pages, read)` returns `read`

Comment: were you trying to return an object?

If so:

return { title, author, pages, read }